# Factoring any single-variable polynomial in $\mathbb C$

Tags: polynomials, algorithms, complex-numbers, factoring

The fundamental theorem of algebra [says](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170071/can-any-polynomial-be-factored-into-the-product-of-linear-expressions)

$$
\forall p(x):\mathbb C \to \mathbb C,\ p(x) = a\prod_{n=0}^m\big(b_nx+c_n\big)
$$

where $p(x)$ is a single-variable polynomial, and $\{a;m\}\cup\{\forall b_n\forall c_n:0\leq n\leq m\}$ is unique (I say that set is unique because the $b$s and $c$s can be exchanged as multiplication is commutative, the $a$ is outside the $\prod$ so the $b$s and $c$s are truly unique). This is, any single-variable polynomial has a unique complete (binomial) factorization in the complex number set.

My question is: how do I factor any polynomial in $\mathbb C$? Not a [specific one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150566/factorization-of-polynomials-over-mathbbc), I'd like an algorithm, a theorem, that can factor any polynomial. I've seen some other posts related to this, but they're always specific to some polynomial and involve long division and some confusing formulas, lemmas and what-nots Wikipedia doesn't help me understand (I've googled around, but as I don't know precisely what method is it I'm looking for, I came up more confused). Anyway, what I mean is that would be helpful, however it is not what I am looking for.

If it is indeed possible to make such an algorithm, is there any site that explains this, any open-source program that is able to do this, do you have any ideas to generalize any method you've come up with? Thanks for reading this, I hope it helps you (especially the first part) help me.

Comment: the bad news is that if you want exact answers, you're out of luck. look up the unsolvability of quintics on wikipedia. using the rational root test you can find all the rational roots though. i'm not sure what numeric method is the best

Comment: You can factor out the leading coefficient from the largest power of $x$, forcing $b_n \equiv 1$. Then, the free coefficient must be the product of the roots. There are transformations you can use for all powers under 5 and at powers 5 or more it's not always possible...

Comment: I only now realize this is basically the same as asking for the solution of any equation, because any solutions would be obvious by the product annulment law (I wonder if that is the real name, I translated it by word, I mean $\displaystyle\prod_n a_n=0\Leftrightarrow \exists i:\exists a_i=0$).

Comment: @exitingcorpse, that means the fundamental theorem of algebra is false? Wikipedia says: «it does say that a general "quintic formula" for the roots of a quintic using only a finite combination of the arithmetic operations and radicals in terms of the coefficients is impossible». Isn't there any way, even if it has tricky non-closed-form expressions, to know the factorization?

Comment: @gt6989b, please read the above comment as well.

Comment: finding roots and finding linear factors is the same thing. the FTA tells us that the roots do exist, and the galois theory tells us that we won't find nice finitary expressions for them in general (maybe you can get series expansions, but still).

Comment: that said, you can use packages like mathematica and sage (i imagine) to find numerical approximations to the roots. i have no idea how well these work in practice

Comment: note that one particular example that is important in the real world is finding eigenvalues, or roots of very specific polynomials. so the problem should be well studied

Comment: @exitingcorpse, «finding roots and finding linear factors is the same thing», yes I noticed that and commented above. «we won't find nice finitary expressions for them in general»; what about non-closed forms, like integrals or infinite products?

Comment: @JMCF125 i'm sorry, i believe there are methods to express the roots as (perhaps repeated) infinite series, but i don't actually know of any results to that effect. it might be better to ask a new question of the form "we can't find roots of general polynomials in terms of radicals, but what other expressions can we find for them?"

Comment: @exitingcorpse, should I edit the question to focus on that? Or I may do as you say and then answer my own question. Thank you for your time, I'll do that as soon as I formulate a good question on my mind.