# Find a solution to any single-variable equation

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, complex-numbers

I know it is not possible to solve any equation of fifth degree and higher "using only a finite combination of the arithmetic operations and radicals in terms of the coefficients" (see on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem)). But is it possible in any way; is there a general formula/theorem/conjecture/algorithm, even if it requires a lot of tricky non-closed form expressions, to know the solution of any single-variable equation? How?

#### Note:

Check [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423831/factoring-any-single-variable-polynomial-in-mathbb-c) and its comments (make sure you read them all, I don't intend to clarify here when I already did there) for background on this question, so before answering "no, it's impossible", consider the fundamental theorem of algebra.

### Edit (for clarity):

More precisely, by solution of a single-variable equation in the complex numbers of degree $n$ (so any function representing one of its members would be $\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$), I mean a subset of $\mathbb C$ with $n$ elements, such that any of those can replace the variable in the equation yielding an equality.

What I'm asking for is **exactly** the following: how can the solution (set described in the above paragraph) for any equation that meets the criteria above be found? Is there a formula? Or at least an algorithm for approximation? How do they work? What's their definition?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

Well, it depends what you mean by a solution.  You can solve fifth degree polynomial equations numerically to arbitrary accuracy, and sometimes solutions can be represented as limits of certain sequences of algebraic expressions.  The statement that there is no quintic formula simply means that there are fifth degree polynomials that can't be solved by radicals - no more, no less.  (Of course, this applies to polynomials of degree $>5$ as well.)

With respect to the fundamental theorem of algebra, this just means that once you have all the zeroes of a polynomial $p$, in whatever way you choose to represent them, the polynomial factors to $$\prod_{p(\alpha)=0} (x-\alpha).$$  If the $\alpha$'s can't be written by radicals, you'll have to write them in some other way.  The nonexistence of a quintic formula doesn't just mean that there are cases for which you can't *find* all the $\alpha$'s by radicals, it means that in these cases you can't even *write* these $\alpha$'s by radicals at all.

Comment: «you'll have to write them in some other way»; the question is: what is that way? Also, please check the updated question.

Comment: @JMCF125 Again, you could use Newton's method to find a numerical approximation.  Some other special cases admit limits as solutions but there is no general way as far as I know.  "$\alpha$ such that $p(\alpha)=0$" is another way of writing these, and as Sharkos points out, is this really much worse than, say, $\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: Yes it is worse, because a solution must always exist. The $\alpha$'s are out there, I want to know how to write them, I don't care if they're mile-long formulas, I care if they are exact values (everything with an approximation has an exact value). And Newton's method just gives approximations, that in some edge cases don't work. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @JMCF125 The whole point is there *aren't* exact formulas, mile long or not, involving only elementary functions.  I propose Newton's method because I find approximate numerical values to be more satisfying than "$\alpha$ such that $p(\alpha)=0$", especially when the values may be computed to be *arbitrarily* precise.  If you don't find that satisfying enough, I'm afraid you're combatting what Galois proved.  The bring radical (as mentioned above) is your best bet.  Just because it *exists* doesn't mean you can write it using standard tools.

Comment: I didn't say anything about **only** elementary formulas. Newton's method only gives approximations, and those require certain [criteria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method#Failure_analysis). It's like if I'd ask for the exact value of $\pi$; I'd like something such as $$\frac{4}{1+\text{K}_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{n^2}{2n+1}\right)}$$ and you were telling me to use polygons to get approximations. (The K is Gauss's continued fraction notation, that I can't get right in TeX).

Comment: @JMCF125 You aren't accepting what you're being told from all sources: there is no known way to do this for all algebraic numbers.

Comment: No? Is the fundamental theorem of algebra false? "to arbitrary accuracy", I interpret this as a possibility to find a limit (successive closer approximations). As when one has consecutive partial sums and find the full sum (or limit as some bound goes to some extreme). Wouldn't this work? If not, why?

Answer (score 2):

Without you specifying some particular notion of what it means to "know a solution", this question isn't particularly clear. For instance, I am perfectly at liberty to define a 'special' function $\Psi:\mathbb R^5\to \mathbb R^5$ (or at least suitable patches thereof) such that $\Psi(a_0,\cdots,a_5)=(x_1,\cdots,x_5)$ are the ordered solutions with multiplicity of $\sum a_ix^i=0$. In terms of this special function, finding solutions is trivial. One can then study this function, which has various properties, and consider that the problem solved. Is this better or worse than the definition of square root? You need to add some criterion of judgement.

In fact, the problem can indeed be brought closer to the definition of the square root as the solution of $x^2=y$ via the use of the Bring radical or hypergeometric functions - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring_radical

If you mean something more specific like algorithms or infinite series expressions, then there is more to say.

There are certainly algorithms to find roots to arbitrary accuracy, of which bisection is the simplest but suffices. If you're happy with infinite series representations, then perhaps you are equally happy with an algorithm to determine the answer to arbitrary accuracy, since these are quite similar.

As for infinite series representations, I don't know whether there are any off the top of my head which work in general, though you can probably make local expansions of the above $\Psi$ away from 'bad' regions which can probably be analyzed separately. Indeed the Bring radical has a series expansion at generic points. The real question is whether this would be interesting or not - from the very little I know, it probably isn't when phrased like this, though perhaps some generalization of the problem would spawn new interest.

Comment: «Without you specifying some particular notion of what it means to "know a solution", this question isn't particularly clear»; thank you, I have clarified the question. The function ($\Psi$) you define does not conform to it now; so I'd like you to update the answer to reflect the changes in the question.

Comment: Yes it does, with tweaking. $\Psi(\mathbf a)$ as a map $\mathbb C^5\to \mathbb C^5$ with arbitrary locally(?) consistent ordering is well defined locally and could also be studied. It will probably have nontrivial winding properties and obvious singularities as the leading coefficient goes to zero which can be eliminated by rescaling and moving to four dimensions. Bisection fails in the complexes but other techniques work.

Comment: Ah! Now I see what you mean (although I don't know what some of the words you used precisely mean). Sorry, when I commented I didn't read that paragraph with enough attention. But couldn't there be a definition of that function that applies to all possibilities (also considering more parameters, and thus higher degree equations)?

Comment: What space would it map into?

Comment: To $\mathbb C^d \to \mathbb C^d$ where $d$ is the degree of the equation. Unless I misunderstood what you said.

Comment: That doesn't apply "to all possibilities", that applies only to degree $d$ equations - you could certainly have one function per degree, but the cases where these functions become annoying are near changes of degree.

Comment: I mean there must be a function like that to each of those all possibilities; that is each set of degree $d$ equations (as you referred to them). What do you mean "near changes of degree"? Half-degrees?